# Appcmd from Bash script replacing backslashes with forward slashes, how to prevent?

Tags: bash, backslash, appcmd

I'm trying to run a `Bash` script which calls `appcmd` to add a site to IIS.

```
#!/bin/bash

windir=c:\\windows
domain="$1"
path="$2"

#also tried using forward slashes by replacing backslashes
#physicalPath=`echo "$path" | sed 's/\\\\/\//g'`

#add site
$windir\\syswow64\\inetsrv\\appcmd add site /name:$domain /physicalpath:$path
```

I'm calling the script using:

> script.sh mydomain.com c:\mypath

However when I check IIS, the Physical Path property of the site is set using **forward slashes** instead of backslashes.

[image: appcmd Bash]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing your sed pattern maybe `sed 's!\/!\\!g'`

Comment: This produces an error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @l'L'l: this produces the same error. But my `sed` part doesn't actually produce an error, it I `echo $physicalPath` the values are replaced. It's just that in `IIS` it will come up with forward slashes which it doesn't understand

Comment: @l'L'l: still the `c:\ mypath` appears in IIS as `c:/ mypath`

Comment: I did notice a few things, and I think you're close; in many examples there's a `-` before the physicalPath... so maybe `-PhysicalPath:"C:\ $path"`, or `-PhysicalPath:"$env:systemdrive\"$path`, or `/[path='/'].physicalPath:%SystemDrive%\$path` ...

Comment: This actually does the trick! Thanks! - So very strangely (mixed `/` and `-` delimiters) I now have this as a working command: `$windir\\syswow64\\inetsrv\\appcmd add site /name:$domain -physicalpath:$physicalPath /bindings:http/*:80:$domain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are used to prevent special treatment of certain characters:

```
$ z=foo
$ echo "$z"
foo
$ echo "\$z"
$z
```

Because of this, you need escape backslashes themselves in order to use them literally. Each pair `\\` is seen by the shell as a single literal `\`.

```
windir=c:\\\\windows
domain="$1"
path="$2"

#add site
"$windir"\\\\syswow64\\\\inetsrv\\\\appcmd add site /name:"$domain" /physicalpath:"$path"
```

However, a simpler way to escape them is to include them in single quotes.

```
windir='c:\\windows'
domain="$1"
path="$2"

#add site
"$windir"'\\syswow64\\inetsrv\\appcmd' add site /name:"$domain" /physicalpath:"$path"
```

(You can use double quotes as well, but since there are a few characters that have special meaning in double quotes, a backslash can be used to escape *them*, which means sometimes you need to escape a backslash, sometimes you don't. For example:

```
$ echo "\$"
$
$ echo "\t"
\t
```

)

Answer (score 1):

does the following data from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725781%28v=ws.10%29.aspx helps?

To change the path of an application's content, use the following syntax:

```
appcmd set app /app.name: string /[path='/'].physicalPath: string
```

The variable app.namestring is the virtual path of the application, and physicalPathstring is the physical path of the application's content.

For example, to change the physical path of the location c:\application for an application named marketing in a site named contoso, type the following at the command prompt, and then press ENTER:

```
appcmd set app /app.name: contoso / marketing /[path='/'].physicalPath:c:\ application
```

For more information about Appcmd.exe, see Appcmd.exe (IIS 7).

Comment: The OP is using variables though, and not hardcoded strings.

Comment: I tried the following command: `$windir\\syswow64\\inetsrv\\appcmd set app /app.name:$domain/ /"[path='/'].physicalPath:$physicalPath"` (note: `domain$/` is appname and also note double quotes around `/"[path=...."`. Still the physical path in IIS is with forward slashes...